# Real-time location of trains in France, Germany, Switzerland, and other countries

Tags: data-request, europe, public-transport, real-time

In Great Britain, [Real Time Trains](http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk) shows the actual departure, arrival, and passing times at any control point (station stop or not) for any train (passenger, freight, or other) anywhere in Great Britain (England, Wales, and Scotland).  Many sites offer a similar service for flights.  In the United States, Amtrak has an interactive map showing where their passenger trains are right now.

Are there any websites offering information similar to Real Time Trains for other European countries, such as France, Switzerland, or Germany?  I'm mostly interested in a service showing *all* trains (passenger, freight, others) at *any* place (station stop or not).  If that doesn't exist, I'm also interested in a website offering information as close to this as publicly available.

Comment: [Similar](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10404/1511)

Comment: Virtual trainspotting...

Comment: Reddit thread with some more resources https://www.reddit.com/r/trains/comments/3pzta1/live_traffic_maps_for_rail/

Answer (score 5):

Finland has a real-time and train tracking website - **[Live Train Map](https://www.vr.fi/cs/vr/en/live_train_map)**

> With the Live train map you can track the movement of trains. The information is based on train GPS tracking.

[direct link](http://188.117.35.14/vrviewer/VrViewer.html?locale=en_US)

[image]

Comment: Is that all trains, or just timetabled regular passenger trains?

Comment: It's passenger trains

Answer (score 4):

For the Netherlands someone built this map showing all passenger trains in currently in operation: http://spoorkaart.mwnn.nl/

This map is based on the data from this website: http://openov.nl/ (in Dutch, scroll all the way down for the data sets)

**Update:**

From [Antony Joseph's answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10404/11218): I believe this might be exactly what you're looking for: http://tracker.geops.ch/

[image: examples from tracker.geops.ch]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a new-ish open source resource for live Swiss trains.

http://maps.vasile.ch/transit-sbb/

> This map is an animation based on the official timetables of the Swiss Federal Railways(SBB) network.
>
> Real time information available from the [GTFS-RT](https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/cookbook/gtfs-rt/) feed by [opentransportdata.swiss](https://opentransportdata.swiss)

[image]