# Is there any international public transport data?

Tags: data-request, transportation, public-transport

I want to create some proof of concept for an international public transport service. Is there any data or an API available that already normalizes this data across multiple countries, besides Google Maps?

Comment: Deutsche Bahn has access to timetables of most other European countries, so that might be a good place to start: https://www.deutschebahn.com/en/start/

Comment: openstreetmap.org doesn't do this, but may give you locations of various bus stops, etc. Probably not complete though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TRAVIC has a list of public transport service APIs that conform to the GTFS standard: http://tracker.geops.ch/

- [List of API Feeds](http://tracker.geops.ch/feeds/) (searchable and filterable)

EDIT: I found a couple of more-direct links to GTFS feeds internationally:

1. TransitFeeds: http://transitfeeds.com/
2. Transit land: https://transit.land/feed-registry/