# Real-time vehicle fleet position data, United Kingdom

Tags: api, transportation, location

I am a software developer. I want to advertise that I can build vehicle tracking apps. To that end, I will place a live demo on my web page.

I am looking for an API which I can query every 5 seconds or so to get the current positions of vehicles and update the map in real-time.

I want something UK based, preferably in London, but that's not a deal breaker; nation-wide would not hurt (and I may even be able to think of a few extra features for it).

I *could* use the London Underground or buses, I suppose. But if I am trying to market fleet tracking capabilities,  might it not be better to use an actual fleet? E.g DHL or something like that? Or, am I just overthinking it and is "data moving on the map"  enough?

I would prefer something with data 24/7, so that people looking from other time zones won't see an empty map in the middle of the night. Taxis? Pizza delivery? Police cars would be great, but I doubt if they make their data public ;-) Hmm, maybe ambulances or fire engines?

In terms of requests to the API, maybe every 5 seconds, possibly every second, but I don't want a messy map, so maybe 5 or 10 vehicles (max 20 if UK wide). The API must, of course, be free for commercial use.

So, which imaginative API can you recommend me? Real-time  not recorded, data please.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10404/1511 (duplicate?)

Comment: or scroll through https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-time