# Where can I find U.S real time train data

Tags: usa, public-transport

I'm looking for something like [The Darwin Push Port](http://nrodwiki.rockshore.net/index.php/Darwin:Push_Port) which broadcasts streams of information about the creation of, and changes to, train schedule records, together with train running predictions for the USA railways.

If not possible for live data - can it be accessible historically? (including train delays and cancellations)

Comment: please edit your question if it's not duplicate - happy to re-open in that case

Comment: also see here for non-US data https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5856/1511