# Railways, trains and timetable data

Tags: data-request, transportation

I have a school project in which I am supposed to analyse how much trains are late at different rail stations. I can create an artificial database for this purpose. However I would really like to use a real data for this project. Where can I find the data in which train courses, timetables, arrival and departure times (and anything else that is involved) is present. The country is unimportant.

EDIT: I am not interested in a website or a system to which I will have to do web scraping. My question is about a database which can be used directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real-time location of trains in France, Germany, Switzerland, and other countries](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/real-time-location-of-trains-in-france-germany-switzerland-and-other-countrie)

Comment: Marked as duplicate (did you search before asking?), and see also https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12114/where-can-i-find-u-s-real-time-train-data

Comment: But there is no access to database over there. To use that sites I need to access data through API which I am possibly unable to do. Are there any ready to use databases?

Comment: @JanDoggen I did search, and I haven't found CSV or SQL database. The attached question does not answer my problem neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swiss [Open Transport Data](https://opentransportdata.swiss/en/) platform has "Ist" (actual) data as a big CSV file, split into individual days.

https://opentransportdata.swiss/en/dataset/istdaten

For one particular day

https://opentransportdata.swiss/en/dataset/istdaten/resource/72d1b1cc-349f-420b-a692-f12c72841607

each file is about 200 MB as uncompressed CSV.

You will probably need to use the fields

- AN_PROGNOSE = to forecast (schedule)
- ANKUNFTSZEIT = arrival time
- AB_PROGNOSE = from forecast (schedule)
- ABFAHRTZEIT = departure time

---

Here's a limited list of applications using the data, you might find some code on Github that saves you some time parsing the file

https://opentransportdata.swiss/en/showcase-2/

[image]